# Laravel octane - Infinite loading on server error

Tags: laravel, swoole, octane

When I get a server error or it encounters a `dd` method, the request hangs forever and no response comes.
[image]

PHP: 8.0.3

Laravel: v8.62

Octane + Swoole

Running in wsl2